# R Markdown: Creating Backgrounds for Powerpoints

Tags: r, r-markdown, visualization

I'm using R markdown to create a presentation, and I would really like to add a custom background on my opening slide and second slide. Currently, I have my potential themes on a separate PowerPoint document. Is there any way to add backgrounds like that?

Thanks!

Comment: RMarkdown supports several libraries for presentations, so it would be important to know which one is used and for which kind of output (PDF or HTML -- or Powerpoint??). For HTML, background images are well supported with **xaringan**, see https://slides.yihui.org/xaringan/ for a presentation.

Comment: I'm using powerpoint...

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom background, one can create a powerpoint template, e.g. `my-styles.pptx` where the background image is placed at the slide master.

Then create an Rmarkdown file like follows and place it in the same folder:

````
---
title: "Fancy Slides"
author: "Creative Author"
date: "2021-06-09"
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: my-styles.pptx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```
````

More about this can be found in Yihui Xie et al. (2021) R Markdown: The Definitive Guide, [Section 4.4.](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/powerpoint-presentation.html#ppt-templates)

Tested with RStudio Version 1.4.1714 and Powerpoint 2016.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I got that far. But my goal is to have the first slide be the same as the first slide in my reference_doc. Then, I'd want to change the background in the second slide. In my template, I have one background for the first slide, another for the second slide, etc. Whenever I try to do that, the computer throws up error 63. Ideas?